# Creating a htmlhelper method to remove quotes in strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, methods

I want to create a **htmlhelper method** in an MVC4 project using Entity Framework 5.0

For one of my pages, descriptions are loaded. Most descriptions are:

```
description description description
```

but some are

```
"description description description"
```

Now how do I write a htmlhelper method that removes these " " quotes?

Below is an example of an already working htmlhelper method that adds three dots for descriptions that are too long:

```
  public static class HtmlHelpers
  {
    public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
    {
      if(input.Length <= length)
        {
          return input;
        }
        else
        {
          return input.Substring(0,length) + "...";
        }
    }
```

So I basically need something like above but with the purpose of not displaying " " quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `String.Trim(Char[])` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) method to get rid of the leading and trailing double quotes in a string.

```
string foo = "\"This is a quoted string\"".Trim('"');
```

Then you don't really need an HTML helper you can just use `Trim()` directly in your view.

```
@Model.Description.Trim('"')
```

Or make it a property of your model :

```
public string DescriptionWithoutQuotes
{
    get { return this.Description.Trim('"'); }
}
```

Using a HTML helper for this would be overkill, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string Unquote(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return string.Empty;

    return input.Replace("\"", "");
}
```